# "Clock set to wrong date" error

Tags: ios, foursquare

I am developing a new IOS app and I am using Foursquare API for venues. For some reason, after 4:00 pm (UTC -3), I receive the following error: "clock set to wrong date". I can't understand why. Does anyone has an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I am using ASIHHTPRequest and for some reason the error happens for no apparent reason. I added:

```
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:YES];
```

and it solved the problem. But I don't know why it fails sometimes.

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394293/how-to-accept-self-signed-certificate-with-asihttprequest)